# Send multipart email (html+plaintext) in Dynamics CRM 2011?

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I'm sending out e-mails in Dynamics CRM 2011 UR13 using my plugin with the following code;

```
// Create the e-mail message
Email email = new Email
{
    To = new ActivityParty[] { toParty },
    From = new ActivityParty[] { fromParty },
    RegardingObjectId = new EntityReference(new_la.EntityLogicalName, la.Id),
    Subject = emailsubject,
    Description = emailbody, // html-content
    DirectionCode = true
};
var _emailId = service.Create(email);

// Send the e-mail message
SendEmailRequest sendEmailreq = new SendEmailRequest
{
    EmailId = _emailId,
    TrackingToken = "",
    IssueSend = true
};
```

The e-mail is being sent to the reciptient, however, the receiving mailservers spamfilter is not happy because the content is html only.

```
X-Spam-Report:  
  *  1.6 HTML_IMAGE_ONLY_24 BODY: HTML: images with 2000-2400 bytes of words
  *  0.0 HTML_MESSAGE BODY: HTML included in message
  *  0.7 MIME_HTML_ONLY BODY: Message only has text/html MIME parts
  *  0.4 HTML_MIME_NO_HTML_TAG HTML-only message, but there is no HTML tag
```

I want to minimize the risk of the e-mails being stuck in our customers mailfilters. Ideally the e-mail should be sent as multipart, i.e. both a text/plain and a text/html part, but I cannot figure out how define the plain text part separately.

So the question is - it there any way to specify one html-part and one plain text-part of the e-mail body?

Answer (score -1):

[This is a how to for PHP](http://kevinjmcmahon.net/articles/22/html-and-plain-text-multipart-email-/) but the same logic should work for a crm email I would think

Comment: Problem is, everything I set Description to, will be the text/html part of the email being sent.

Comment: @Magnus I'm not exactly an expert here but it seems that is what the _boundary_ tag in the _$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/alternative;boundary=" . $boundary . "\r\n";_ is for. Are you finding that a sent email, created via the email entity, doesn't behave per the example in the link?

Comment: @Magnus if you are using exchange you may not need the text part. see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7956527/how-can-i-send-a-multi-part-email-with-text-plain-and-text-html-with-exchange-we)

Comment: I've now tried changing the settings of my user in CRM, so "E-mail access type outgoing" is set to "E-mail Router" (via our Exchange server) insted of "CRM for Outlook" as before, I still get the same result as before though - that is, the text/plain part is not generated.

Answer (score -2):

You need to remove the header and the footer.

```
body.Substring(body.IndexOf("<p"), body.LastIndexOf("</p>") - body.IndexOf("<p"));
```